# How to pass one element of a vector to a function as reference in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, vector

I'm trying to manipulate the values of a 0-initialized vector in a loop in C++.
However when I print out the values of the vector it shows only sensible values inside the "myFunction". Outside of it the values did not change.
Here is a sketch of my example:

```
vector<float> meanDistances(numDescriptors);  

for (int i = 0; i < numDescriptors, i++)  
{
    myFunction(arg1, arg2,...,meanDistances[i]));
    cout << "meanDistance OUTSIDE myFunction: " << meanDistances[i] << endl;
}
```

This is how "myFunction" looks like:

```
void myFunction(arg1, arg2, ..., float & meanDistance)
{
    meanDistance = someFloatNumber;
    cout << "meanDistance INSIDE myFunction: " << meanDistance << endl;
}
```

How can I pass single elements of my vector as reference to a function?

Edit:
here is some more code

```
boost::thread_group threadGroup;
for (int i = 0; i < numDescs ; i++ )
{
    int threadIdx = i % numThreads;

    vecHists[i].convertTo(vecHists[i], CV_32F);
    threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind( &myFunction, vecHists[i],vecHists[i],vecDistanceMats[threadIdx], meanDistances[i]));



    sleep(1);

    if(threadIdx == numThreads-1 || i == numDescs-1)
    {
        threadGroup.join_all();
        for (int j = 0; j < numThreads ; j++)
        {
            sumDistanceMats += vecDistanceMats[j];
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < numDescs ; i++ )
{
  cout << "meanDistances OUTSIDE myFunction after all threads are joined again: " << meanDistances[i] << endl;
}
```

Edit2:
It turns out that the problem in this function rather lies in the functionality of `boost::threadGroup`. If I exchange the `vector<float> meanDistances` vector by a vector of 1x1 dim opencv Mats `vector<cv::Mat> meanDistances` everything is working fine.
Of course I'm also modifying `myFunction` accordingly:

```
void myFunction(arg1, arg2, ..., Mat& matMeanDistance)
{
    meanDistance.at<float>(0,0) = someFloatNumber;
    cout << "meanDistance INSIDE myFunction: " << matMeanDistance.at<float>(0,0) << endl;
}
```

So somehow `boost::threadGroup` treats vectors of `float`s different than vectors of `cv::Mat`

Comment: vector's [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) return a ref, so that should work.

Comment: Provide a proper test case (your sample is not showing anything)

Comment: From what I can see of your code, it should work. Could you post more of your code? Preferably a concise and complete example that still has the same problem.

Comment: Your edit doesn't explain what `myFunction` corresponds to in your actual code. Is it thread_group::create_thread?

Comment: Sharing unprotected data in different threads is no good: `int threadIdx = i % numThreads;`

Comment: You need to follow the "Minimal Complete Verifiable Example" idea, which is on the help section of the site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Break your problem into that, and then figure out why your "actual code" is failing if your test example works.

Comment: So,  the problem is most likely due to the result being calculated in a different thread. If that thread doesn't assign the value before the calling thread performs the cout statement you won't see any changes in mean distance.

Comment: Thx for your comments but the problem remains unfortunately. Even when I place the cout to look at  "meanDistances" outside the entire loop, the results still don't correspond to the values INSIDE the myFunction. Might be that the problem lies with boost threadGroup but I don't see whats wrong.

Comment: This seems really to be a weird error. So if I replace the vector<float> meanDistances variable by a vector of 1x1 opencv Mats   vector<cv::Mat>. The whole thing is working and "myFunction" is returning the correct numbers. It seems like 'boost::threadGroup' is treating vectors of elementary objects (like floats) differently than vectors of higher (class) objects (like cv::Mat).

Answer (score 0):

Below you will find an example on how I would modify all elements in a vector either via reference (using a *range-for*) or via the `std::transform` algorithm aided by a lambda.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// utility function to print to screen
template<typename T>
void show(const T& v) {
  for(const auto & vi : v) {
    std::cout << vi << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

// function used to modify by reference
void fun(double arg, double& vi) {
  vi += arg;
}

int main() {

  // initialize ten elements to 0.0
  std::vector<double> v(10, 0.0);
  std::cout << "Initialized as: " << std::endl;
  show(v);

  // modification using references in a loop
  for(auto & vi : v) {
    fun(2.0, vi);
  }
  std::cout << "Modified to: " << std::endl;
  show(v);

  // modification using an algorithm and a lambda (this one modifies by value)
  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(),
                 [](double vi) { return vi + 3; });
  std::cout << "Modified using std::transform() and lambda" << std::endl;
  show(v);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ example.cpp -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out
Initialized as:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Modified to:
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
Modified using std::transform() and lambda
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Hmm yes this seems to work. However it seems now that I rather have a problem with manipulating the entries of a vector inside a loop producing different thread via boot::threadGroup